IIS pools stoping after a lot of Warnings
Since yesterday, we started noticing 503 errors in production, where lots of warnings can be seen are stopping the IIS pools.
The errors in Windows Server Event log are:
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GeneXus.XML.GXXMLReader.AppendNode(GXSOAPContext ctx, Node node, Int32 extent)
   at GeneXus.XML.GXXMLReader.Read()
   at GeneXus.Programs.arecepcao.webExecute()
   at GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)

It seems like it occurs before entering the application code. Maybe a malformed request the client is sending to the webservice, but we can't capture the request inside the system, because the error occurs before enter the code.
My question is how do I solve this issue?

You showed the error, but maybe you can show the requests you believe are responsible as well ?

unfortunetly I have no ideia which request could be doing, it was just a gess. Ou system receives more than 3k request every minute in around 30 types of requests.

To know more details, configure logging. This article may help: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?43303,Log4net+configuration+in+GeneXus+.Net+application

@ArminBachmann This morning it started happening again. The unique weird log that was recording on client.log is:
12:35:18,906 [576] WARN  GxContext - Client timezone not found:
NodaTime.TimeZones.DateTimeZoneNotFoundException: Time zone  is unknown to source TZDB: 2023c (mapping: $Revision$)
at NodaTime.TimeZones.DateTimeZoneCache.get_Item(String id)
at GeneXus.Application.GxContext.get_ClientTimeZoneId()
12:35:18,906 [576] WARN  GxContext - Setting Client timezone to System default: America/Sao_Paulo

You should review the "arecepcao" object because that's where the execution is happening and the error is occurring. It might have a configuration file with an incorrect format. In the worst case, you could delete that object so that everything continues to function until that object is debugged.

arecepcao is my web service soap. It was running good for days and today at 9 a.m. stared with this trouble. I'll try to put a try catch, but I guess the erros haven before enter the code section
